# The LINQ expression could not be translated when trying to use .All() to List<string>

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

My linq query fails when I try to execute it on db side:

```
public async Task<List<MatchEntity>> GetMatchesAsync(List<string> teammatesChampionNames, List<string> enemiesChampionNames)
    {
        return await _context.Matches.Include(x => x.Teams).ThenInclude(x => x.Participants).AsSplitQuery()
            .Where(x =>
                teammatesChampionNames.All(y => x.Teams.Any(z => z.Participants.Any(i => i.ChampionName == y)))
                && enemiesChampionNames.All(y => x.Teams.Any(z => z.Participants.Any(i => i.ChampionName == y)))).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Do you know whether it is possible to rewrite it? I am using .EF Core 7 and SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first condition (`teammatesChampionNames.All...`), the idea is that if all `ChampionName`s of all `Particiants` of all `Teams` are collected, you want the `Matches` where *all* of these names occur in `teammatesChampionNames`. This is true if `teammatesChampionNames` contains these names *and* when there are as many of these occurring names as there are in `teammatesChampionNames`.

Applying the same reasoning to the second condition, the query can be rewritten in this form that EF can translate:

```cs
return await
(
    from match in _context.Matches
    let championNames = match.Teams
        .SelectMany(x => x.Participants)
            .Select(p => p.ChampionName)
    let teammates = championNames.Where(n => teammatesChampionNames.Contains(n)).Distinct()
    let enemies = championNames.Where(n => enemiesChampionNames.Contains(n)).Distinct()
    where teammates.Count() = teammatesChampionNames.Count()
       && enemies.Count() = enemiesChampionNames.Count()
).ToListAsync((;
```