# Return multiple count from linq query

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have two arrays of strings with champion names in request. I want to calculate wins and loses for matches where one team contains champions from request.TeamChampionNames and other team contains champions from request.EnemyChampionNames. There are only 2 teams in 1 match. Each champion is unique. Only 1 team can win match, and I can know this from MatchTeam or MatchParticipant. Can this query be rewritten so all the work is executed on database side?
Query was taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129514/18470394

Code:

```
var matches = await
            (from match in _context.Set<Match>()
                let participants = match.Teams
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Participants)
                    .Select(p => new { p.ChampionName, p.Win })
                let teammates = participants.Where(participant => request.TeamChampionNames.Contains(participant.ChampionName))
                let enemies = participants.Where(participant => request.EnemyChampionNames.Contains(participant.ChampionName))
                where teammates.Count() == request.TeamChampionNames.Count()
                      && enemies.Count() == request.EnemyChampionNames.Count()
                select teammates.First().Win // selecting whether teammates win
                )
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        var winRates = new TeamWinRateResponse
        {
            Wins = matches.Count(hasWon => hasWon),
            Loses = matches.Count(hasWon => !hasWon)
        };
```

Models:

```
public record WinRateGetQuery : IRequest<TeamWinRateResponse>
{
    public required IEnumerable<string> TeamChampionNames { get; init; }
    public required IEnumerable<string> EnemyChampionNames { get; init; }
}

public class Match
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    
    public virtual ICollection<MatchTeam> Teams { get; set; } = new HashSet<MatchTeam>();
}

public class MatchParticipant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ChampionName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Win { get; set; }

    public string TeamId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual MatchTeam Team { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class MatchTeam
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Win { get; set; }

    public string MatchId { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Match Match { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<MatchParticipant> Participants { get; set; } = new HashSet<MatchParticipant>();
}
```

In database it looks like this:

Teams table for one match:

[image]

Participants table for one match:
[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by wanting to execute all the work on the database? Maybe we can find something better for you with that knowledge.

Comment: I want to calculate wins and loses for matches which contain champions from teammates list in one team and champions from enemies list in other team. There are only two teams in match

Comment: OK, so why is it a problem if some of the work is done on the client? (You might have an XY problem.)

Comment: For rewriting this query model classes are needed. And describe in question in more detail what this query do.

Comment: Well, because I don't want to load records from db into server memory. Added more description and models, hope it helps

Comment: @AndrewMorton why wouldn't you want to do it in the database? But it is a good point, a query like this can be expensive on really large datasets so you might prefer a hybrid approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine the whole thing into one query, rather than doing `ToListAsync`.

Also it might get a more efficient query if you do `select teammates.Max(x => x.Win)` instead of `select teammates.First().Win`.

```cs
var winRates = (
    from match in _context.Set<Match>()

    from teamWin in (
        from team = match.Teams
        from participant in Participants
        where request.TeamChampionNames.Contains(participant.ChampionName)
        select participant
        group by 1 into g  // use constant to do GROUP BY ()
        select new { Count = g.Count(), IsWin = g.Max(p => (int)p.Win) }
    )

    from enemy in (
        from team = match.Teams
        from participant in Participants
        where request.EnemyChampionNames.Contains(participant.ChampionName)
        select participant
        group by 1 into g  // use constant to do GROUP BY ()
        select new { Count = g.Count() }
    )

    where teamWin.Count == request.TeamChampionNames.Count()
       && enemy.Count == request.EnemyChampionNames.Count()
    select teamWin.IsWin // selecting whether teammates win

    group by 1 into matches  // use a constant to do GROUP BY ()
    select new TeamWinRateResponse
    {
        Wins = matches.Count(hasWon => (bool)hasWon),
        Loses = matches.Count(hasWon => !(bool)hasWon)
    }
).FirstAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: I've tried to do such thing: https://pastebin.com/m6xwrf7X. I am getting  Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. Also I've shared models in description, please let me know what is unclear about my question

Comment: Can you share the result of `ToQueryString()` for this query? Sounds like a bug I've seen before in EF but might be able to workaround it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wURqf21k

Comment: OK see new edits

Comment: Thank you, this works: https://pastebin.com/ABsWmbEU. However, if I use max as you adviced: https://pastebin.com/g28Ajrzn, I am getting such error: Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator. I am just curios in what cases max function is better. Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: I've managed to use max in such way: https://pastebin.com/CjBZes4P. I compared queries generated by EF(max and first), they're identical :). Thanks again

Comment: Yes that's a typical workaround for a `bit` column aggregation. Another method is to convert to `int`.